# ESO - Condition/curse stacking

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Ok... I've tried for a while to find a clear answer to this, but the closest I got was here (https://www.reddit.com/r/elderscrollsonline/comments/2n2uti/do_dots_stack/). Unfortunately is still not clear for me.

Let's take an example to explain what I don't get. Say we got 2 werewolves - because it has 2 different types of strong conditions (me and a friend).

```
1. Let's say I (first ww) bleed for 8k dmg/8 sec. on each hit.
2. Second ww bleeds for 10k dmg/8 sec. on each hit.
3. First ww poisons for 6k dmg/hit (5th skill, Claws).
4. Second ww poisons for 7k.
5. First ww has Claws of Life morph (drains 50% of the poison damage).
```

Let's assume **for simplicity** that all further attacks are instant (you can hit twice in 0 seconds).

Now this is what I got from different posts:

```
1. If first of the ww hits twice, the bleeding is not stacked in intensity (they give the normal bleed damage - 8k, over 8 seconds).
2. If first ww bleed, then poisons, the damage is stacked - 14k dmg.
```

And... that's it :). Further cases are still a mystery to me.

```
1. First ww hits (bleeds) and second ww hits (bleeds). How does this stack? The result is 18k dmg (total)? The condition is rewritten at each hit (whoever hits last gives the dmg)? Or the higher damage remains (in this case 10k)?
2. Same for poison.
3. For poison, if both ww apply poison, do the first ww heals over time (Claws of Life)?
```

Any other cases that I haven't considered are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't test this right now, it should work pretty much like this:

- If the effect you're applying is a named buff/debuff (e.g. Minor Fortitude, Major Brutality, Minor Shatter, Minor Maim, etc.), only the strongest will be applied/persist (or reset its duration in case they're equal).
- If the effect you're applying isn't named as a buff/debuff, like it's just a general bleeding or some other damage over time effect (e.g. poison), it should be limited to once per attacker.

So if both of you hit someone with a light attack, you both should see your own bleeding effect being applied (and constantly reset in case you attack again).